# Identical hashes returned from lambda behaving differently

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip for uploads to a Rails 4 image server. We want to track different image sizes and be able to generate new sizes on the fly if an existing style with the requested size does not exist.

To do this we have, in addition to a `Photo` model, a `Size` model belonging to `Photo`. I'm using a `lambda` to generate a hash object from `photo.instance.sizes` and pass that into Paperclip's `:styles` parameter. The hash gets generated just fine and when I log it to standard output I see a hash with the default size in Paperclip's desired format. `{:medium=>"300x300#"}` (worth noting the keys in the generated hash are symbolic, Paperclip doesn't like string keys)

When this hash is being returned from the `lambda`, no additional styles are generated and only the original resolution is saved. However, when I return a hard-coded hash (`default` var in code below) with the same contents, the additional style "medium" is generated (along with the original).

I made sure the hard coded hash was exactly the same as the one generated from `photo.instance.sizes` by logging an `===` comparison which returns true.

Here's the `has_attached_file` from the Photo model:

```
has_attached_file :asset,
                  :styles => lambda { |photo|
                    # Empty hash will contain paperclip formatted style options
                    styles = {}
                    # Get instance of model and iterate over its sizes
                    photo.instance.sizes.each do |size|
                      # Paperclip style format { :style_name => "WIDTHxHEIGHT#" } trailing pound means crop and retain aspect ratio
                      styles[size.name.to_sym] = "#{size.width}x#{size.height}#"
                    end
                    # default = { medium: "300x300#" }
                    styles
                  },
                  :storage => :s3,
                  :path => "/assets/:idhash/:style.:extension",
                  :s3_credentials => {:bucket => ENV["AWS_BUCKET"], :access_key_id => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"], :secret_access_key => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET"]}
```

Any insight (or an alternative) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: On first glance everything seems to be as described in https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#dynamic-styles and implemention seems to be fine too https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L196

Comment: Is the file first attached or is the size-object linked first? Normally styles are rendered when the file is attached inside [assign](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L114); beside the private function post_process there seems to be no way to afterwards create new sizes.

Comment: You can probably use reprocess! to add sizes. Documentation does not sound that great though. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L332